# Difference in maven webapp project creation using NetBeans and CLI

Tags: maven, netbeans

I recently noticed that NetBeans creates a Maven webapp project structure differently than Maven command-line interface.

## Maven Command-line interface:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.test.mavenwebapp -DartifactId=climvnproj -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

## Project Structure Created through command-line interface:

```
climvnproj
----pom.xml
----src/main/resources
----src/main/webapp
```

## Project Structure Created through NetBeans IDE:

```
mavenwebproject1
----pom.xml        
----src/main/java
----src/main/webapp
```

After examining the logs in NetBeans I can see that the NetBeans used following archetypeId

```
-DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee6
```

Shouldn't NetBeans IDE and CLI have consistent output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netbeans is not using the maven-archetype-webapp archetype but a set of archetypes maintained by netbeans devs at [org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-*](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/archetypes/) always one selected by the javaee version selected by the user. Same applies to ejb/ear archetypes.

That's because the default archetype is fairly ancient and not optimized for javaee5+